# Parenthesis after UIViewController

Tags: objective-c

I saw some code when studying the open source project: [here](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck). 
But I can't figure out the meaning after I checked Objective-C syntax.

The code looks like this:

```
@interface UIViewController (UIViewDeckItem) 
@property(nonatomic,readonly,retain) IIViewDeckController *viewDeckController;  
@end

@implementation UIViewController (UIViewDeckItem) 
@dynamic viewDeckController;
...
@end

@implementation UIViewController (UIViewDeckController_ViewContainmentEmulation_Fakes) 
...
@end
```

Not sure where I can find the related Obejctive-C info about this implementation.

Comment: I think its called Category. It is used when you want to add methods to a class but dont want to Inherit from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

**Categories and Extensions**

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html